# Conditional expression in PyTables where method

Tags: python, where-clause, pytables

I want to use conditional expression in PyTables where method. In SQL, I would use CASE expression (PostgreSQL, "CASE WHEN a=b THAN 1 ELSE 0"), if usual python, I would use conditional expression "1 if a==b else 0". But I couldn't find how it can be done in PyTables `where` method.

I checked http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/condition_syntax.html but I don't know if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where(predicate, num1, num2)`.

```
table.where('where(a==b, 1, 0) == c')
```

According to [Conditional Syntax](http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/condition_syntax.html)

> where(bool, number1, number2): number - number1 if the bool condition
>   is true, number2 otherwise.

Comment: I didn't check it. Thank you.